# setParameters failed when setting sepia, but zoom works fine

Tags: android, camera

I am making an app which employs the camera. When it starts up it executes code to check the capabilities of the camera. One check I do is the following:

```
    List<String> supported_colour_effects_list = java_recording_camera_parameters.getSupportedColorEffects();

    Mylog("There are "+supported_colour_effects_list.size()+" supported colour effects");
    for (int i = 0;i < supported_colour_effects_list.size();i++)
    {
        Mylog("Colour effect: ["+supported_colour_effects_list.get(i)+"]");
    }
```

When this code executes, I see the following output:

```
I/xx(11517): There are 12 supported colour effects
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [none]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [mono]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [negative]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [solarize]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [sepia]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [posterize]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [whiteboard]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [blackboard]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [aqua]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [emboss]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [sketch]
I/xx(11517): Colour effect: [neon]
```

The program then continues and I can view a continuous preview of what the camera sees. If I press a button to instigate the following code...

```
    java_recording_camera_parameters.setZoom(75);
    java_camera_for_recording.setParameters(java_recording_camera_parameters);
```

then everything works exactly as expected, you can see the preview image suddenly zoom in. Bit if I swap the line `java_recording_camera_parameters.setZoom(75);` for `java_recording_camera_parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_SEPIA);` then, when I press that same button then I get the following error...

```
W/System.err(4128): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
W/System.err(4128):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
W/System.err(4128):     at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1551)
```

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it works (or doesn't). On some devices some settings that are declared to be supported, fail. Sometimes it fails with RuntimeException, but often - silently: you set preview size to 320x240 on a Galaxy Nexus, but the callback brings back VGA frames.

Some settings are not compatible with the others: maybe Sepia is not compatible with your preview size, or must be set while preview is stopped.

One good test would be to see if you can choose Sepia in the built-in camera app on the same device.

Comment: Sounds like you are talking from bitter experience!

Comment: Yes, just tested - the built in camera app also crashes when you set sepia!

Comment: Which device would that be?

Comment: A prototype device... I can say no more!

Comment: Yes, it's fun to work with half-cooked devices, especially when the ODM keep their cards close to the chest.